# Open file in racket and use regex on said file to print matches

Tags: regex, file, pattern-matching, match, racket

I have been trying to use regular expressions in racket on a text file full of random words separated by the end of line character `\n`. I'm trying to read in the file as a string or list (whichever is easiest and most intuitive) and use regex to print all the words in the file of length 6 that does not contain a certain letter (in this case the letter t). Below you can see how I read in the file  but I am not sure how to use its resulting list because of the lack of variables. Also you can see below I try a test with regex that's true outcome is `#f` when I actually want the words `grumpy` and `foobar` returned excluding `stumpy`.

```
    #lang racket
    (require 2htdp/batch-io)
    (require racket/match)

    ;(file->string "words.txt");;reads in a file to a string
    ;(file->list "words.txt);; reads in a file to a list

    (define (listMatches)

      (regexp-match #rx"\b[^<t> | ^<T> | ^<\n>]{<6>}\b" "grumpy\nstumpy\nfoobar" )

     )
```

I am very new to Racket and would love some input, useful links, and any other help.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use a regex at all, but rather use [`for/list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for%2Flist#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29), in combination with [`string-length`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=string-length#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-length%29%29) and [`string-countains?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=string-contains%3F#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstring..rkt%29._string-contains~3f%29%29) to solve the problem. The overall solution looks something like this:

```
(call-with-input-file* "words.txt"
  (lambda (f)
    (for/list ([i (in-lines f)]
               #:when (and (= (string-length i) 6)
                           (not (string-contains? i "t"))))
      i)))
```

The use of [`call-with-input-file*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/file-ports.html?q=call-with-input-file*#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._call-with-input-file*%29%29) takes a procedure, and in this case binds `f` to an open file. This way we do not need to close the file ourselves when we are done with it.

Finally, `string-contains?` was added relatively recently to Racket. And if you need to support older versions of Racket, you can use [`regexp-match`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html?q=string-match#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._regexp-match%29%29) to just search for "t", which is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things Racket regular expressions can take as a value to match a regular expression against is an input port. This means you can look for matches in a file without having to first read from it; the matching code will do that part for you. Combine with using multi-line mode so that `^` and `$` match after and before newlines as well as the very beginning and end of the input, and you get a simple approach using [`regexp-match*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._regexp-match%2A%29%29) and a RE that matches 6 non-t characters on a line by themselves:

```lisp
#lang racket/base

(require racket/port)

;;; Using a string port to demonstrate
(define input "grumpy\nstumpy\nfoobar")

(define (list-matches inp)
  (map bytes->string/utf-8 (regexp-match* #px"(?m:^[^t]{6}$)" inp)))

(println (call-with-input-string input list-matches)) ; '("grumpy" "foobar")
```

The big thing to remember about using an input port is that what it returns are *byte* strings; you have to convert them to strings yourself.